# Why I cannot using cookies variable value outside the cookie.get function?

Tags: electron

I just began to learning using electron. 
I have set a cookie and I want using it value.

```
    function getCookie(cname) {
      var value = {
        name: cname
      };
      session.defaultSession.cookies.get(value, function (error, cookies) {
        let cookieStr = ''
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
          let info = cookies[i];
          cookieStr += `${info.name}=${info.value};`;
          console.log(info.value, info.name);
          let somevalue = info.value;
        }
        console.log(cookieStr);
        alert(somevalue); //alert 1
      });
      alert(somevalue); //alert 2
    }
</script>
```

I got the `cookieStr` value in console.log.

Then in somewhere place, I want to use `cookieStr` value by calling `getcookie(cname)` but it keep undefined. How to use the cookie value outside the function?
I have tried display the value with 'alert 1' inside the cookie.get function and it is work. But, the 'alert 2' which outside cookie.get function keep displaying undefined.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading cookies in electron is an asynchronous function. So its better to call the the function with a callback to return value. or else promisify the function.

```
    function getCookie(cname,callback) {
      var value = {
        name: cname
      };
      session.defaultSession.cookies.get(value, function (error, cookies) {
        let cookieStr = ''
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
          let info = cookies[i];
          cookieStr += `${info.name}=${info.value};`;
          console.log(info.value, info.name);
          let somevalue = info.value;
        }
        callback(cookieStr);
      });
      //alert(somevalue); //alert 2
    }

getCookie('test',function(returnValue){
//use the return value here
})
```